# how to activate the red light in MC67

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

i'm working on MC67 with windows mobile 6.0 and Motorola symbol.dll.

I need to light the red light in the device. i looked at the Motorola example and they don't show a way to do it, which makes me think there is no way to do it with symbol.dll.

is there a different way to do it? or do you know a general way to light the red led in the MC67? i'm talking on the red light because i already succeeded lighting all the others using Motorola Symbol.dll

Answer (score 1):

There is a class LED in Symbol.Notification namespace (EMDK .Net by Motorola).

I'm not tried but i think it helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: EMDK .Net is buggy a little. You can try EMDK for c. It work better and have better documentation.

Answer (score 0):

All LEDs on WM are normally accessible using the NLED API. The problem is that you have to find the ID for the red LED yourself:

First get the number of LEDs:

```
    NLED_COUNT_INFO cInfo;
memset(&cInfo, 0, sizeof(cInfo));
NLedGetDeviceInfo(NLED_COUNT_INFO_ID, &cInfo);
```

Then check each LED ID using LED ON/OFF (some support BLINK):

```
/*
struct NLED_SETTINGS_INFO
{
UINT    LedNum;                 // @FIELD   LED number, 0 is first LED
INT     OffOnBlink;             // @FIELD   0 == off, 1 == on, 2 == blink
LONG    TotalCycleTime;         // @FIELD   total cycle time of a blink in microseconds
LONG    OnTime;                 // @FIELD   on time of a cycle in microseconds
LONG    OffTime;                // @FIELD   off time of a cycle in microseconds
INT     MetaCycleOn;            // @FIELD   number of on blink cycles
INT     MetaCycleOff;           // @FIELD   number of off blink cycles
};

*/
NLED_SETTINGS_INFO settings; 
memset(&settings, 0, sizeof(settings));
settings.LedNum= id;
/*  0 Off 
    1 On 
    2 Blink */
settings.OffOnBlink= onoff;
settings.TotalCycleTime=1000;
settings.OnTime = 500;
settings.OffTime=500;
settings.MetaCycleOn=5;
settings.MetaCycleOff=5;

if (!NLedSetDevice(NLED_SETTINGS_INFO_ID, &settings))
{
        DEBUGMSG(true,(L"NLedSetDevice(NLED_SETTINGS_INFO_ID) failed"));
}
else
{
        DEBUGMSG(true,(L"NLedSetDevice(NLED_SETTINGS_INFO_ID) success"));
}
```

PhoneGap has a CS interface for the above C API: https://github.com/hemisphire/phonegap-winmo/blob/master/NotificationCommand.cs

The above works on all WM devices not only Motorola. It is a more general approach than using OEM SDK which will not work on other devices.