# HTC HD2 Windows Mobile Turn off hardware key backlight LEDs

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

I would like to turn off the hardware key led backlights on an HTC HD2 device running Windows Mobile 6.5.  I have tried both reducing and setting the following registry entries to 0 but there was no affect even after doing soft-reset and verifying the settings.

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Backlight\QKeyLedTimeout         0
HKCU\Control Panel\Backlight\QKeyLedBrightness      0
HKCU\Control Panel\Backlight\QKeyLedOnOff           0
```

Does anybody know if this is possible to do on the WM6.5 HTC HD2?

Comment: Looks like HTC does not offer a WM SDK at https://htcdev.com. Possibly the keypad backlight is controlled by one of the NLED values. Just try the NLED API and iterate thru all available IDs. For an example look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993056/how-to-activate-the-red-light-in-mc67

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting API, but it appears it allows you to turn on and off the led's but not necessarily disable them.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Correct, turn LED off/on